# BK3001BA Keyboard not connecting after entering correct passcode

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth

I can't seem to connect my BA3001BA Bluetooth keyboard to my mac. It pairs, and then asks for a passcode. I enter the passcode and I get the spinning beachball of death and shortly thereafter, it says the pairing wasn't successful. I managed to connect the device to an Ubuntu Laptop by bypassing the passcode, but it's not possible on a mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in my experimenting I stumbled upon the Bluetooth file transfer app. I was desperate it seems so I tried sending a file to my keyboard. It ended up connecting and entering the passcode worked this time. No clue why, but it worked somehow.

I couldn't find anything like this via google, although a few people seemed to have the same problem, so leaving it here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

type in 123456 into the passcode on your computer

press connect

then after pressing connect - type 123456 and then press "enter" on your wireless keyboard.

Comment: Oh my. It's been years since I've had this keyboard. I wish I could test your theory to verify it. Thanks for the answer anyway!